# Bibilography does not appear at the end of file. bibliography.bib not screened through the main.tex file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I downloaded the files (`main.tex` and `sample.bib`) from [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5eb52196889b4b0001c64968) in one same folder as an example for bibliography management. 
Here the `main.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Import the bibliography file

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography %Prints bibliography

\end{document}
```

Here the `sample.bib` file:

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}

@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = "1973",
   chapter = "1.2",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@article{ctan,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
```

It does indeed compile with neat bibliography at the end as follows (on the website of overleaf through the browser):

[image]

However when I compile the file locally on my machine (with `pdflatex` command in `Terminal`), the bibliography does not appear and the citations seem broken.

[image: io]

Here the end of the `main.log` file

```
\openout3 = `main.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'main.bbl' not found.

No file main.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 9.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 9.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'einstein' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'dirac' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 12.

[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'main.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `main.run.xml'.
```

I also copied `sample.bib` into a second file `sample.bbl` but nothing changed

**EDIT**
Thanks to the comments below I run the command `biber main` which created a `main.bbl` file which content is as follows:

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 3.0 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \datalist[entry]{nty/global//global/global}
    \entry{dirac}{book}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=59342ede3a101402b34939644b51ad06}{%
           family={Dirac},
           familyi={D\bibinitperiod},
           given={Paul\bibnamedelimb Adrien\bibnamedelima Maurice},
           giveni={P\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim A\bibinitperiod\bibinitdelim M\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \list{publisher}{1}{%
        {Clarendon Press}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{59342ede3a101402b34939644b51ad06}
      \strng{fullhash}{59342ede3a101402b34939644b51ad06}
      \strng{bibnamehash}{59342ede3a101402b34939644b51ad06}
      \strng{authorbibnamehash}{59342ede3a101402b34939644b51ad06}
      \strng{authornamehash}{59342ede3a101402b34939644b51ad06}
      \strng{authorfullhash}{59342ede3a101402b34939644b51ad06}
      \field{sortinit}{D}
      \field{sortinithash}{2ef1bd9a78cc71eb74d7231c635177b8}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{isbn}{9780198520115}
      \field{series}{International series of monographs on physics}
      \field{title}{The Principles of Quantum Mechanics}
      \field{year}{1981}
      \keyw{physics}
    \endentry
    \entry{einstein}{article}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=3ebf53e52a3ce84f0ffb8553200a6a63}{%
           family={Einstein},
           familyi={E\bibinitperiod},
           given={Albert},
           giveni={A\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{3ebf53e52a3ce84f0ffb8553200a6a63}
      \strng{fullhash}{3ebf53e52a3ce84f0ffb8553200a6a63}
      \strng{bibnamehash}{3ebf53e52a3ce84f0ffb8553200a6a63}
      \strng{authorbibnamehash}{3ebf53e52a3ce84f0ffb8553200a6a63}
      \strng{authornamehash}{3ebf53e52a3ce84f0ffb8553200a6a63}
      \strng{authorfullhash}{3ebf53e52a3ce84f0ffb8553200a6a63}
      \field{sortinit}{E}
      \field{sortinithash}{f615fb9c6fba11c6f962fb3fd599810e}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{journaltitle}{Annalen der Physik}
      \field{number}{10}
      \field{title}{{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{ö}rper}. ({German}) [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]}
      \field{volume}{322}
      \field{year}{1905}
      \field{pages}{891\bibrangedash 921}
      \range{pages}{31}
      \verb{doi}
      \verb http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004
      \endverb
      \keyw{physics}
    \endentry
  \enddatalist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

Comment: Running pdflatex isn't enough. You also have to push a button to take care of the bibliography. After that, pdflatex again.

Comment: Many thanks @Johannes_B. I use mainly terminal to generate the pdf from the `.tex` file. How could I do it in terminal?

Comment: Use `biber main`

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback @Johannes_B. I ran the command `biber main` in the terminal. It did generated a `main.bbl`. I copied the content in the edit of the question. What should I do next to have the bibliography in the `main.tex` file?

Comment: Run pdflatex again. -> https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: It worked indeed Many thanks!! @Johannes_B

Comment: The whole process of producing a bibliography is brilliantly explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. Would you agree that your question is a duplicate of that?

Comment: @moewe yes of course. Indeed I didn't see that one. Thanks for the feedback